# Is It Possible to Deep Link in Data Studio?

Tags: deep-linking, looker-studio

I have a Google Data Studio report that displays the hits different links receive. What I'd like to be able to do is for a user to come from a link and have the report by default filter out data from all links except that one.

Is there any feasible way to get the link from the page that referred the user to the report? Or is this just not possible?

Thanks!

Comment: Great question to which, sadly, I am pretty sure the answer is No.

Comment: You can also ask in the Data Studio forum - https://www.en.advertisercommunity.com/t5/Data-Studio/bd-p/Data-Studio

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution we reached is slightly different than what I was looking for, but we found the option to allow the user to bookmark URLs under File -> Report Settings.

This should make it possible to give users these bookmarked links to the report so that it only shows the filtered link data. Just thought I'd follow up in case anyone else wanted to deep link in data studio as well!